# getting full URL in php without white spaces

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, share

I am trying to share the full URL from my website to whatsapp using mobile browser,
I tried this to retrieve the full URL and it works perfectly when I echo the variable, but when I share using the mobile browser, it gives me the link with white space like this: **http://127.0.0.1/?id= 40**
 which can not be opened, how can I get the full echoed link without no spaces?

```html
   <?php
    $alink= (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ?

            "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    ?>
    

//To Share
    <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $message['title'] ?> <?php echo "\r\n" ?> <?php echo $alink ?> <?php echo "\r\n" ?> <?php echo $myText ?>"
                           data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share To Whatsapp</a>
```

Comment: You are putting parameters into an URL context here, but you neglected to apply proper URL encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$alink = str_replace(' ', '', $alink)
```

[Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

The standard conditions `[$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on']` do not work on servers behind a load balancer:

```
$isSecure = false;
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
        $isSecure = true;
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on') {
        $isSecure = true;
    }
    $REQUEST_PROTOCOL = $isSecure ? 'https' : 'http';

    echo $REQUEST_PROTOCOL."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the full url by javascript with `window.location.href`
iny my `file.php`

```
...
<div id="url"></div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.querySelector('#url').innertHTML = window.location.href
</script>
```