# echo variables with break(new line) in php

Tags: php, html, echo, newline, break

I have tried a lot of ways to echo each variable in new line but I couldn't get it done

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $message['title']?> <?php echo "\n" ?> <?php echo $mylinkId ?> <?php echo "\n" ?> <?php echo $myText ?>"
```

how can I echo each variable in new line?

Comment: Does `echo "<br/>";` not work?

Comment: Never seen URL with newlines inside. You need to URLencode it.

Comment: @MarkusZeller pretty sure I already told them that, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60069643/10955263, but they seem to do some account hopping here.

Comment: @04FS It feels like people are creating new accounts to ask (dumb) questions because they are afraid of bad reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URLencode it.

```php
<?php
    $plain = join(PHP_EOL, [$message['title'], $mylinkId, $myText]);
    $encoded = urlencode($plain);
?>
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?=$encoded?>">Click me</a>
```